# tooltip in R by gvisTimeline, googleVis

Tags: r, google-visualization, tooltip

How can I show a tooltip by gvisTimeline  in R, my code is:

```
  library(googleVis)

 datTL <- data.frame(Position=c(rep("President", 3), rep("Vice", 3)),
                Name=c("Washington", "Adams", "Jefferson",
                       "Adams", "Jefferson", "Burr"),
                start=as.Date(x=rep(c("1789-03-29", "1797-02-03", 
                                      "1801-02-03"),2)),
                end=as.Date(x=rep(c("1797-02-03", "1801-02-03", 
                                    "1809-02-03"),2)),
                Position.html.tooltip=paste('<p><nobr>',  format(round(c(0.460, 5.100, 
  2.393,2.3,2.2,3.33), 2), nsmall = 2), 'm<sup>3</sup></nobr></p>'))

  Timeline <- gvisTimeline(datTL, 
                     rowlabel="Name",
                     barlabel="Position",
                     start="start", 
                     end="end",
                     options=list(tooltip="{isHtml:'true'}")   )
 plot(Timeline)
```

No tooltip is shown.

Comment: not familiar with R, or the package you're using, only google charts. but the tooltip column for a timeline must come after the bar label column in the data table, and before the start and end dates. see the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#data-format) -- also, don't see the column headings, but the column heading for the tootlip must be represented by object notation when using java script --> `{role: 'tooltip', type: 'string', p: {html: true}}`

Comment: you should probably post the correct code as the answer, I'm sure it could help someone...

Comment: Thanks again, put me close to answer, Not sure what shall I do now, I can post the right code, or if you can post it I will accept it as the answer, so the code is : Position.html.tooltip should come immediately after Position, Postion should come after Name , so the order is Name, Position,Position.html.tooltip (in the first part), and for the second part: barlabel="Position", should be changed to barlabel=c("Position","Position.html.tooltip" ).based on my trials, the order is not that important in the first part, having Position.html.tooltip in the dataframe is the key, and have it in barbel

Comment: Thanks will do, but it was your answer put me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to WhiteHat

```
 datTL <- data.frame(
                Name=c("Washington", "Adams", "Jefferson",
                       "Adams", "Jefferson", "Burr"),
                Position=c(rep("President", 3), rep("Vice", 3)),
                Position.html.tooltip=paste('<p><nobr>',  format(round(c(0.460, 5.100, 
                                                                         2.393,2.3,2.2,3.33), 2), nsmall = 2), 'm<sup>3</sup></nobr></p>'),

                start=as.Date(x=rep(c("1789-03-29", "1797-02-03", 
                                      "1801-02-03"),2)),
                end=as.Date(x=rep(c("1797-02-03", "1801-02-03", 
                                    "1809-02-03"),2))
               )

  Timeline <- gvisTimeline(datTL, 
                     rowlabel="Name",
                     barlabel=c("Position","Position.html.tooltip" ),
                     start="start", 
                     end="end",
                     options=list(tooltip="{isHtml:'true'}") 
                                  )   
 plot(Timeline)
```

Based on my experience in R, the order of the first part is not important, we need to have 
 Position.html.tooltip in the dataframe(i.e. datTL$Position.html.tooltip) and then have this in the barbel as shown above in the second part